# setting toolbar height programmatically doesn't work on android 4.4

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I try to change the height of my toolbar programmatically:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =  toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (displayWidth / 1024) * 580;
toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
toolbar.requestLayout();
```

the toolbar is defined like this in my xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bbtest"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:longClickable="false">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

on android 8.0 this works like a charm. But on my android 4.4.2 tablet the height of the toolbar reduces to zero when doing this.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: in android 4.4, `(displayWidth / 1024) * 580` = ?. I guess your `displayWidth` is integer and it < 1024 then `(displayWidth / 1024) * 580` = 0

Comment: @PhanVanLinh omg how did I not see this. So simple. Please write an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I face some small problem like you many time too. And the interesting is I take a lot of time for fix small problem because I never thing it is the problem :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your 4.4 device, the `displayWidth` is integer format and it < 1024 then `(displayWidth / 1024) * 580 = 0`.
Therefore, it make your toolbar invisible.
The solution is you can change `displayWidth` to float (or double) or change the operator to `displayWidth * 580 / 1024`